# Passing an array in Fortran function without size argument

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

I am very new in Fortran programming world. I am trying to write a function `find` in Fortran which accomplish the same as MATLAB's `find()` or Python's `numpy.where()` to be included in LS-DYNA UMAT. I can't use `findloc` function introduced in Fortran 2008 as LS-DYNA recognizes Fortran 90 in fixed format. The following function is executing properly, but I have to send the size of the array as an argument.

```
      program test
        integer*8, parameter:: n = 5
        integer*8:: var(n), val

        var = (/2,9,4,5,8/)
        val = 9

        index  = find(var,n,val)
        print *, index
      end program test


      function find(array,n,val) result(loc)
      implicit none
      integer*8:: i,n,val,loc
      integer*8:: array(n)

      do i = 1,n
        if (array(i) .eq. val) then
          loc = i
          exit
        else
          loc = 0
        endif
      end do

      return
      end function find
```

When I tried to modify the code to send an array without a size as function argument as follows, the array is not passed. Your help would be appreciated to modify the function to pass an array without size (n) argument.

```
      program test
        integer*8, parameter:: n = 5
        integer*8:: var(n), val

        var = (/2,9,4,5,8/)
        val = 9

        index  = find(var,val)
        print *, index
      end program test


      function find(array,val) result(loc)
      implicit none
      integer*8:: i,n,val,loc
      integer*8:: array(:)
      n = size(array)

      do i = 1,n
        if (array(i) .eq. val) then
          loc = i
          exit
        else
          loc = 0
        endif
      end do

      return
      end function find
```

I also tried following code snippets to make the function working, but no luck!

```
      integer*8, allocatable:: array(:)
      n = size(array)
      allocate(array(n))
      ...
      ...
      deallocate(array)
      ...
      ...
```